# Why react router redirects from the parameter route to '/'?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following router structure:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path={'/books'}>
            <p>All books</p>
        </Route>
        <Route path={'/books/:bookId'}>
            <p>book with ID</p>
        </Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Whenever I navigate to `/books/:bookID`, after a split second there, I got redirected back to `/books`. No Redirects present, but I got pushed back to `/books` with putting url manually, or using `history.push()`.

`<Link />` can't be used, but it didn't help as well.

```
<Button onClick={() => history.push('/books/5')}>Go to book 5</Button>
```

Would be glad to any hint on this matter.

Comment: Any code about the routing event launcher?

Comment: I've updated the code